# Tomcat: Can't connect from other computer on LAN

Tags: linux, tomcat, ip, firewall, lan

I have installed Tomcat on Oracle Linux 7. I changed the default port from 8080 to 8088.  I am able to connect and browse the default apps using Firefox at http://[myhostname]:
8088 on the same computer.
However, none of the following works on the same computer:

- http://localhost:8088
- http://127.0.0.1:8088
- http://192.168.0.4:8088 (the current DHCP-assigned IP address of the machine)

Moreover (and this is the ultimate goal), I cannot browse the webapps from another computer on the same (home) LAN.
I CAN connect via SSH from the other computer (running Ubuntu 14) using the IP address of the host/server computer that is running Tomcat, but again I can't connect to the Tomcat apps.

Consider me a noob in Linux until proven otherwise.

I am not sure if a firewall is blocking port 8088. I made no changes to any default settings since installing Oracle Linux 7.

ATTEMPTS AND CLUES (some more random than others):
Output of

```
netstat -an | grep 80 
...includes the following:
tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::8089                 :::*                    LISTEN  

ss -l | grep 80
nl     UNCONN     0      0      audit:auditd/801             *                     
u_str  LISTEN     0      80     /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock 28094                 * 0                    
udp    UNCONN     0      0       *:43802                 *:*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      80     :::mysql                :::*                    
tcp    LISTEN     0      100    :::8089                 :::*
```

I notice that I do NOT see 8088 in this output. Don't know if that is significant or not.

```
service iptables stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop  iptables.service
Failed to stop iptables.service: Unit iptables.service not loaded.

yum install system-config-firewall
Loaded plugins: langpacks, ulninfo
No package system-config-firewall available.
Error: Nothing to do

apt-get update
bash: apt-get: command not found...
```

Please advise more promising lines of inquiry, and the rationales behind them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

```
tcp6  0  0  :::8088  :::*  LISTEN
```

It looks like tomcat only listen on IPv6, while you try to use IPv4 addresses.

Does adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to your `CATALINA_OPTS` fix it ? (it seems listening on `0.0.0.0` [could help too](http://www.fourproc.com/2012/04/20/force-tomcat-to-use-ipv4-on-server-with-both-ipv6-and-ipv4-configured.html)).

Comment: Thanks David, I made the configuration change from IPv6 to IPv4, but that doesn't seem to have had any effect. For comparison I installed Tomcat on Windows (swapped hard drive on laptop) and noted that it works correctly pretty much out of the box. That is, http://[MyHostName]:8088, http://localhost:8088, http://127.0.0.1:8088 and http://192.168.0.5:8088 all work locally. The one glitch for accessing from another computer was to open the ports on the Windows firewall. On my Oracle Linux installation, the only URL that works is http://[MyHostName]:8088.  The others give a blank page, no error.

Comment: When I attempt to connect from the other computer using the explicit address 192.168.0.5:8088, likewise there is no error, just a blank page. I suspect that if I could get all the URL variations to work locally, the explicit IP address would work from the other computer.

Comment: I have configured firewalld to open the ports 8080-8099, to no apparent effect.

Comment: Try with [`-Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses` too](http://serverfault.com/a/391027/367929). Don't forget to restart tomcat. Check with `ps aux|grep java` that the tomcat process *does* have these options (if not, you changed the wrong file). Then, check with `ss`/`netstat` that you listen on `0.0.0.0:8088` (IPv4), not just `:::8088` (IPv6).

Comment: ps aux|grep Djava #output includes:
tomcat    6636  0.0  1.8 5507620 146840 pts/1  Sl   Nov25   0:09 /home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.73/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses

Comment: netstat -an | grep 80 

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8089            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! Sometime early in this journey I had edited the server.xml file to change [Host name="localhost"] to [Host name="(MyHostName)"]. That is why only "http://MyHostName:8080" worked and none of the others.  Now that I have changed it back to "localhost" in server.xml, all 4 variations work locally and yes, I can reach the Tomcat webpage from the other computer using http://192.168.0.5:8080.
Thanks to everyone who offered their help and support.

Comment: Btw, did NOT put an address attribute in the <Connector> tag in server.xml in my final version.  Not necessary, apparently.